# Solving the following quartic equation : $x^4- {31\over 4}x^3 + {21\over 4}x + {9\over 2} = 0$

Tags: polynomials, solution-verification

So, I don't know if it's normal but this quartic seems long to solve...

When I use the ferrari method, I get the following reduced quartic :

$y^4 - {2883\over 128}y^2-{27103\over 512}y-{1809027\over 65536}=0$

Now, on paper, I did reduce the reduced quartic to a cubic form... But the numbers keep getting worser. Is it normal ? I don't have the courage to calculate all of this, if it correct :(

Thank yoU!

Comment: We invented computers to stop this insanity! But if you insist, keep going for another 1/2 hour then compare to the computers answer (which it'll generate in less than 30 seconds)

Comment: Yes, I know about Wolfram Alpha ! It was killing me, so I just stopped !

Comment: Wolfram or the by hand method? If you insist on doing it by hand, just use newton's method (best of both worlds)

Comment: Well, I began by hand and stopped after it was getting too long. I don't know Newton's method.

Comment: Then go learn about it. It can approximate solutions to *any* polynomial equation, and more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find:

$$4x^4-31x^3+21x=-18$$

$$x(4x^3-31x^2+21)=-18$$

$$4x^4-31x^3+21x+18=0$$

$$x((4x-31)x^2+21)+18=0$$

And the answer is very difficult/hard to find!